# What handwriting APIs can help me with this?

Tags: android, handwriting

I want to create an application that recognizes handwriting on the screen. I don't need it to recognize insanely difficult words; just simple stuff like "A" "BC" "Z" (maybe some shapes, but could be without this). How do people usually go about this? Are there any famous handwriting recognitions that i can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to recognize single letters and shapes alike I would suggest using `GestureOverlayView`.

Read about it here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html

here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

and here:

http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/articles/gestures.html

It is said to be good for casting HarryPotter-like spells too.

Comment: Thanks, i just tried it out, and it's working really well. just what i needed. I do have another question if you could answer: Is it possible to have your phone's lockscreen to be a GestureOverlayView?

Comment: @rx24race I don't think so.