# Looking for Handwriting OCR Android libraries

Tags: android, handwriting-recognition

I´m looking for some useful API or libraries for handwriting recognition in Android. I want to integrate it in my app but I don´t find anything. I saw in other post that it´s possible using Tesseract(but this work better for OCR image text recognition).

Also I found this API https://dev.myscript.com/ , but it doesn't work fine. Anyone of the demos that they provide work correctly in the phone. It crash when I write a lot or just tab the screen. I tried to follow their tutorials to integrate it in a single app with a single Widget and it doesn't work.

Someone knows some way to integrate handwriting recognition? It´s just for a simple view where I want to write something in the screen throught Handwriting and put the text in a EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are quite a few options out there.

The following [Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159724/what-handwriting-apis-can-help-me-with-this) answers your question.

You can also have a look at [PhatWare](http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=page/writepadsdk/android) and [Lipi Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lipitk/files/Lipi%20Toolkit/lipi_toolkit4.0_android/)

Comment: Thank you TejjD, I created a Android Gesture dictionary and I´m using it to set the text as handwritting!

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark as correct :)

Comment: Done! Thank you very much!